# Display of impact calculation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, people-reached

My impact reached is showing *1k* but I know it is be higher. For example, it could be 1200 which is greater than *1k*.

Another example is a user has *654k* reputation but it shows like 654,234 on his profile.

Why doesn't it show the exact number?

Comment: It's an estimation, no accurate value. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) for explanation.

Comment: @Asif.Ali why no research? i.e. searching for whether this question has already been asked and answered?

Comment: @Asif.Ali you understand that's indistinguishable from not doing any research which is a downvote reason listed on the downvote tooltip.

Comment: *Another example is a user has 654k reputation but it shows like 654,234 on his profile.*  Its called rounding.  There is only so much space to display the user card.  Instead of showing it exactly they round to the nearest K to save space.

Comment: @Asif.Ali even rep gets rounded in your user card that is shown in answers because of _space constraint_

Comment: Because the number is almost useless.  It is just a guess.  For a lot of people it can be kind of close but all it takes is answering a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), get a couple of up votes on the answer, and all of the sudden you'll have 175K people reached when we all know that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://data.stackexchange.com for researching this.

As Rene suggested: Check a sample [query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1).
You can enter your user id number for running it.

Comment: better use [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1?UserId=811) or my own cross-site people reached query: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246194/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user/254178#254178 I'm not sure what DavidG was up to but that query is not even close to cover the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks. will update the post

Comment: @Asif.Ali what about http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user?accountid=281857

Comment: @Asif.Ali you need to enter your https://stackexchange.com id. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user?accountid=1435254 this is mine

Comment: @rene the url still contains your account :)

Comment: @suraj it looks like we hit a race condition on SEDE. We get each others cached results somehow ...

Comment: also relevant to explain large jumps in the number: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251662/158100

Comment: @rene the url is not getting updated with the new parameter..

Comment: right, [this one is correct](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user?accountid=7015566) ... I hope ...  what a mess ...

Comment: @rene yes..thats the one..still way off 1k.